# Serving up an Angular 1.x application in Express with static directories exposed

Tags: angularjs, express

I have an Express server that is setup as so:

```
// src/server/server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/libs', express.static('./node_modules/'));
app.use('/app', express.static('./src/client/app'));
app.use(express.static('./src/client'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./src/client/app/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8001;
var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

The static directory exposure seems awkward (and not correct) to me.

My project structure looks like this:

```
/project
  /node_nodules
  /src
    /client
      /app
        app.js
        my.controller.js
      index.html
    /server
      server.js
  package.json
```

All in all, this allows my index.html to serve files as such:

```
<!-- src/client/index.html -->
<body>
    <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/form.controller.js"></script>

    <div ng-controller="FormController as formController">
        {{formController.message}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Whether I use a build process to bring dependencies out of `node_modules` or not, my Express setup just doesn't look right to me.

Is there a better way to go about exposing static directories using Express than what I'm using above?

Comment: we use static directories, I put all the statics inside a `dist` folder and expose that: https://github.com/Jewelbots/www/blob/master/main.js#L27  seems to work for us.

Comment: Is the path here wrong? `res.sendFile('./src/client/app/index.html', { root: __dirname });` it doesn't match the file structure you presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gulp` or any task runners to bundle your source codes, and put them into one folder, and only expose that folder to front-end,

for example, you could bundle `angular` and `jquery` libraries into one file called `vendor.bundle.js`, and bundle `app.js` and `form.controller.js` into `app.bundle.js`, then put these two files into `dist/` folder under `project`, the folder structure something like:

```
/project
  /node_nodules
  /dist
    vendor.bundle.js
    app.bundle.js
  /src
    /client
      /app
        app.js
        my.controller.js
      index.html
  /server
    server.js
  package.json
```

then in your express config, you can only expose `dist` folder:

```
app.use(express.static('./dist'));
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <script src="dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/app.bundle.js"></script>

    <div ng-controller="FormController as formController">
        {{formController.message}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: that's the exact thing we use; we have a gulp task for doing that: https://github.com/Jewelbots/www/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L23